# java8 remove objects from list of objects basis condition

Tags: java, collections, java-8

Lets say i have a model

```
Class Travellers{
    private int travellerId;
    private String routeId
    private int came;
    private int gone;
}
```

so a traveller can go (attribute `came`) a `route` and come back (attribute 
 `gone`). I am trying to remove any traveller who has completed the round trip. Example entry :

```
id      routeId     came        gone
1       R1          1           0
1       R1          0           1
2       R2          0           1
```

So `R1` should be filtered out and only `R2` be left post function

Basically, `removeRoundTrips` should help me with leaving only folks who have `came` or `gone` only.

```
private List<Travellers> removeRoundTrips(List<Travellers> travellers){
    // right now its a classic 'for' loop here
    // expectation of something like

    travellers.stream()
                .filter( traveller -> someFunctionWhichFilters)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())

}
```

is there a way to achieve this in streaming / filtering in java8?

Comment: are you looking for any travellers with `came && gone == false` ?

Comment: something like that but its value could be anywhere between `1..10`!!

Comment: then `came` and `gone` should not be in boolean

Comment: sorry..my bad, corrected the entity...!!

Comment: A `filter` only looks at 1 element at a time. You would somehow need to "squash" the elements with the same `id` and `routeId`, and then do the filtering with the predicate `came > 0 && gone > 0`.

Comment: @marstran exactly......that _somehow_ is the key i am struggling to figure!!

Comment: are you specfically only looking for answers in streaming/filtering ?

Comment: @mkjh : `for / iterators` i already have....if you have anything else, i am up for it!

Comment: You have to explain the meaning of “came” and “gone” further. When they have values between one and ten, what is that supposed to mean? Is a route completed when both are non-zero or when they have the same (non-zero) value? What if a traveler completed multiple routes? Why do you store these things as separated items in the first place? Why is the class named “Travellers” when it actually does not even store a single traveler but a fraction of their data?

Comment: @Holger ... whoa...slow down sensei...let me try to answer -> between 1 and 10, any value means he `came` and `gone`, why i mentioned it before is to avoid answers trying boolean operation || route is complete with any value > 0 for both `came` and `gone` present || it will have different `routeId` in that case ( _meaning a new row_ ), for last 2 ques -> its just a sample schema !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to *merge* instances that have the same `travellerId` and `routeId`, summing their `came` and `gone` attributes. For this, you could have the following utility method in some `TravellersUtility` helper class:

```
public final class TravellersUtility {

    private TravellersUtility() { }

    public static Travellers merge(Travellers left, Travellers right) {
        Travellers t = new Travellers();
        t.setRouteId(left.getRouteId());
        t.setTravellerId(left.getTravellerId());
        t.setCame(left.getCame() + right.getCame());
        t.setGone(left.getGone() + right.getGone());
        return t;
    }
}
```

Then, you could use the above method to *reduce* your `List<Travellers>` by using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Map<List<Object>, Travellers> grouped = travellers.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                              t -> Arrays.asList(t.getTravellerId(), t.getRouteId()),
                              Function.identity(),
                              TravellersUtility::merge));
```

This *groups* `Travellers` instances by `(travellerId, routeId)` pair and merges them when there is any collision, summing their `came` and `gone` fields.

Now, we are ready to remove `Travellers` instances from the values of the map that haven't completed a roundtrip:

```
grouped.values().removeIf(t -> t.getCame() > 0 && t.getGone() > 0);
```

To remove such instances, we're using the [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method. If you are OK with a `Collection<Travellers>`, you're done. If you need a `List<Travellers>`, simply do:

```
List<Travellers> result = new ArrayList<>(grouped.values());
```

Comment: like mentioned in comments this is the _somehow_ i struggled to figure in `that somehow is the key i am struggling to figure`!!

Answer (score 1):

```
private static List<Travellers> removeRoundTrips(List<Travellers> travellers) {
    return travellers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Travellers::getRouteId)).values().stream()
                     .filter(v -> v.stream().anyMatch(value -> value.getCame() > 0) ^ v.stream().anyMatch(value -> value.getGone() > 0))
                     .map(values -> values.iterator().next())
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: one entity will have only either `came` / `gone`, not both, so this wont work i guess!